# Open Graph object showing different with each story

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

Okay, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong in Open Graph, but here goes. I've got 3 stories in my Open Graph, which are three different actions linked to one object type.

```
Make A Pledge To -> Cause
Create -> Cause
Log Expense For -> Cause
```

Here is what the three look like in the sample section (I'm pretty sure they look like that in the actual timeline as well).

Make a pledge to a cause:
[image]

Create a cause:
[image]

Log an expense for a cause:
[image]

Is there a reason why the "make a pledge" layout is different? Both objects are actual objects on my website, parsed via providing the url to Facebook's sample data tool. I've set the caption in the "make a pledge" story to the same as the "create" story, but the description and cause target that appears in the "create" story doesn't appear in the "make a pledge" story.

Could someone help me on this? Is there a way I can make the "make a pledge" story look like the "create" story? Or is this something Facebook decides?

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue across stories in my application. Further, it has seemed that while working on my self-hosted open graph objects and the facebook story configuration I'll sometime see the layout change back to the horizontal view for some time.

Comment: Do you know if the images you were using for the create a cause and log an expense stories were small or not in existence? Maybe with facebook shifting toward a visual focused layout they use the thumbnail looking layout for larger images. Just a thought.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks for the reply, I just only saw this in my SO inbox :\ As far as I know all have the same image. The object that I'm pointing to for all three stories is in fact the same, the cause itself (I chose not to specify the expense and the pledge as objects themselves, merely actions, as they don't have their own URL), so logically the same image should get parsed for all three. Oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook uses both formats – and which gets chosen is not up to you or any settings you make/picture formats you use, but Facebook themselves decides that. It might even be one or the other for different users viewing one and the same story.

They do that to test out the formats, and see which one is more “successful”, meaning which one generates more user interaction.

---

(Can’t point you to a source for that, but is has been confirmed by Facebook employees in the Facebook Developers Group.)

Comment: That was my fear, sure makes for an annoying user experience when you have a specific use case.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook checks if an image is available on the referenced site/link. If it finds it, it shows a slightly different format. Your second two actions didn't have an image in the reference.