# Get bigger Display Picture on Sharing link on facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I researched a lot but i did not find best solution for my problem.

When I share any link of my blog post on facebook then it shows very small display Picture.

But I want fully large picture when we share a link. 
Today i saw a facebook link with a very large size. So I came to know that its possible to have large size of image on sharing the link at facebook.

So please some one give me the best solution for this.

[This](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/2860219?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1378900879&Signature=GIlk7%2FglpieNiRyqFa7qoxmMYcg%3D) is screenshot of the post shared on facebook with large preview:

Comment: What do you want, elaborate? And what have you tried yet?

Comment: This is about Open Graph objects published with an action, but for normal link shares the same thing applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683792/open-graph-object-showing-different-with-each-story